# Enabling Hardware Acceleration in Arch Linux with Integrated Graphics

Tags: arch-linux, graphics

Basic Idea of my issue: trying to enable hardware acceleration on my arch system, but when verifying VA-API, I run into the following error:

```
$ vainfo
libva error: /usr/lib/dri/iHD_drv_video.so init failed
vaInitialize failed with error code 1 (operation failed),exit
```

My CPU is an `Intel i7-10510U`, and its integrated GPU is `Intel CometLake-U GT2 [UHD Graphics]`

When following the arch wiki, I installed the `intel-media-driver` package (because of my newer CPU), and made sure to set the environment variable: `LIBVA_DRIVER_NAME="iHD"`, but the issue still remains when checking VA-API.

I tried using the `libva-intel-driver` as well to see if it would give me any different errors, but its the same (instead with `i965_drv_video.so` in the error output)

Some checks that I've ran say that hardware acceleration is enabled, but when i try to launch my desired applications (parsec and moonlight) they claim that I do not have a compatible hardware accelerated video decoder.

Comment: Check `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` and see if the iHD driver has been loaded.

Comment: @Bib It seems like it is being loaded, here are two lines from the log file:

`intel(0): [DRI2]   DRI driver: i965` and
`intel(0): [DRI2]   VDPAU driver: va_gl`

I believe its using the `i965` driver because I installed libva-intel-driver and rebooted to see if that would fix it, so I imagine once i uninstall that it will switch back to `iHD`.

Comment: You want to check what `LIBVA_DRIVER_NAME` is set to, it should be `iHD`.

Comment: @Bib confirmed it is set to `iHD`, still same issue

Comment: The only other thing I can suggest, is to run `strace vainfo` and check whether any system calls are failing, and to check the contents of `/etc/libva.conf` if it exists.

Comment: Do you have `libva-mesa-driver` installed?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I have the very same problem on my Lenovo t14 Intel